# handling obj file without normal

Tags: glsl, shader, webgl

I am trying to build an obj file loader and I have written code to read an obj file with face f with v/vt/vn - vertex, texture coordinate, and normal.

While going through the obj file, there are so many files without normal coordinates.

My shader code in Fragment shader is:

```
float lambertianFactor = clamp(dot(normal, lightDirectionNormalized), 0.0, 1.0);
vec3 diffuseTextureData = texture(diffuseSampler, v_texCord).rgb;
vec3 effectiveDiffuse = diffuseTextureData*diffuse*lambertianFactor*directionalLight;    
effectiveDiffuse = diffuseTextureData*diffuse*lambertianFactor;
```

for obj file without normal coordinate but with diffuse texture, how am I supposed to handle diffuse lighting?

Comment: You need to generate the normal vectors from the faces using the cross product. This cannot be done in the vertex or fragment shader.

Comment: @pravinpoudel each face of the obj file is (should be) a convex polygon so take 3 consequent vertexes from it `(p0,p1,p2)` and then simply compute normal as `n = normalize(cross( p1-p0 , p2-p1))` on CPU side or in Geometry shader, beware wavefront does not have strict polygon winding rule so you need to handle the normal `n` as both sided .. meaning you have to use `abs(dot(normal, lightDirectionNormalized))`

Comment: Well actually, @Rabbid76s comment isn't entirely correct. You could just generate the normals using derivatives of the vertex position in the fragment shader. For that you need to enable `#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable` in the shader, pass the vertex position from vertex to fragment shader via a `varying`, and then use _Spektres_ formula where `p0` is the passed through vertex position, `p1` is `dFdx(p0)` and `p2` is `dFdy(p0)`. With this technique you only have "flat" normals tho where often you want to average normals across faces to achieve gouraud shading.